# How to assign a function to ref using useRef with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm new to typescript. I want to assign a function to a ref in a custom hook. So that the function doesn't change over the render.

Codesandbox link. https://codesandbox.io/s/918l0wro4r

```
function something(params?: any) {
  console.error('params: ', params);
}
const someRef = React.useRef(null); //how do i assign type here.
async function someAsyncFunc() {
  try {
    const a = await something();
    something(a);
  } catch (error) {
    something(error);
  }
}

someRef.current = someAsyncFunc; // ts error here. need help here
```

Answer (score 4):

`useRef` is a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). You need to add a type parameter to tell TypeScript what values you want to use. In your case the ref's initialisation code will look like that:

```
const someRef = React.useRef<Function>()
```

`Function` type allows for any function to be used as a reference. You might want to narrow it a bit in case you have a specific shape in mind. For example, in your case it would be like that:

```
const someRef = React.useRef<() => Promise<void>>();
async function someAsyncFunc() {
  // ...
}
someRef.current = someAsyncFunc;
```